# How to locate the paper that established Robinson Arithmetic?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, proof-theory, theories-of-arithmetic, paper-request

If I'm not mistaken, it was in his seminal paper “An Essentially Undecidable Axiom System”, published in

*Proceedings of the International Congress of Mathematicians (1950)*, 1952:729–730,

where R.M. Robinson proved that Gödel Incompleteness Theorem still applies to Peano Axioms if we drop the induction schema (hence showing that infinite axiomatization is not necessary for essential undecidability), in what we now call Robinson Arithmetic.

I would like to know:

- Is actually this paper what I should be looking for?
- Can it be found anywhere on the net? (I already tried on MathSciNet, SpringerLink, JSTOR and Google Scholar, without success)
- Can anyone pinpoint to closely related, or at least similar, accessible papers?

(Note: I already have the book "Undecidable theories", which he published in collaboration with Tarski, but I'd prefer to locate papers about 'Robinson theory', specifically).

Comment: Two related papers are - Jones & Shepherdson, *Variants of Robinson's essentially undecidable theory ${\rm R}$.* MR0710365 - Vaught, *On a theorem of Cobham concerning undecidable theories*, MR0156788

Comment: All the ICM Proceedings can now be found, and searched, at
http://mathunion.org/ICM/

Comment: All the proceedings of the ICMs: http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/

Comment: One can easily find the cited work via the links given by John Stillwell and Felipe Voloch.  However, it is only a one-page abstract.  It seems that contributed papers were not actually printed in the Proceedings?

Comment: Did you find it?

Comment: @AndersLundstedt No, just the summary published in the ICM proceedings, but it is very informative. You can find it at page 737 of this pdf:
https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1950.1/ICM1950.1.ocr.pdf

Comment: Thanks, yes it was indeed informative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi Jose,
it's in the British library collection:
http://snurl.com/z16ud
Haven't checked what the fees are, but you could order it from there.

Alternatively, you could try the LMS:
http://www.lms.ac.uk
A good chance they will have the procs in their library, and you can get photocopies for a nominal fee.

Several other similar alternatives too.

Comment: Thanks Bob! But I'd like to find it 'online' (i.e., in electronic format), if possible (if not, I will resort to your nice suggestions!)

Comment: Oh, on a closer inspection I see that the British Library offers the option of sending an electronic copy, but the fee is indeed a bit high (over 8 pounds). I'd like to get free access to the article from my University, if possible.



Comment: I know this is not a discussion blog , I make it short :  
How disgraceful it is to have to pay for work that was done with our taxes!!  

Comment: As of 2023, good full-text pdf’s of all past ICM proceedings are available from the IMU website at https://www.mathunion.org/icm/proceedings  The abstract cited in the question is in Vol I of the 1950 proceedings, near the end; as noted in comments on question, it’s a 1-page abstract, not a full paper, but it is very clear and self-contained.